# Setting an ImageView as a MapOverlay

Tags: android, google-maps, imageview, drawable

I currently am using a drawable as a Mapoverlay after following this tutorial .
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Using this I can set a picture to be displayed on a certain position over the map. However I would like to resize the drawable and also have a black boarder around it. I thought my best option would be to have an imageView as a mapoverlay instead of the drawable thus enabling me to set the padding, background color and size fairly easily however I am not sure if this is possible.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to achieve this?